# MySQL INSERT on Condition match against existing row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a reservation system where I am trying to write a query that can insert checkIn & checkOut on condition that don't have conflict.

STRUCTURE

```
id  order_id    room_id    first_date    last_date
--  --------    -------    ----------    ----------
1   00001       A          2015-01-01    2015-01-02
```

PHP

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO date_tbl 
    (order_id, room_id, first_night, last_night) 
    VALUE (:order_id, :room_id, :first_night, :last_night) ');

$count = count($first_date);
$i = 0;

for($i;$i<$count;$i++) {
    $stmt->execute([
        ':order_id' => $this->order_id,
        ':room_id' => $room_id,
        ':first_night' => $first_date[$i]->format('Y-m-d'),
        ':last_night' => $last_date[$i]->format('Y-m-d')
    ]);
}

$dbh->commit();
```

here is where I am having problem. I want to write

```
WHERE first_night > each row's last_night 
OR last_night < each row's first_night
```

I understand there is no WHERE in INSERT, how do I do it?

EDIT:

```
INSERT INTO date_tbl 
(order_id, room_id, first_night, last_night) 
VALUE (:order_id, :room_id, :first_night, :last_night)
SELECT first_night, last_night FROM date_tbl 
WHERE :first_night > first_night 
OR :last_night < last_night
```

maybe this is how you do it???

Comment: Why don't you select records from the table and then check for validity to determine if an insert is appropriate?

Comment: `insert` has no `where` clause. it's not the inserts job to determine if the record should be inserted or not. it's YOUR job to do that. So do the checking in client-side code.

Comment: I was hopping I can do all in one query? is it possible? I am looking at INSERT...SELECT and NOT IN... but I am very lost from reading the documentation.

Comment: I post an edit to the question, can you take a look at it?